# number of DOM nodes are significantly different between chrome lighthouse and performance monitor

Tags: dom, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I measured the number of DOM nodes in [this site](https://github.com/microsoft/CSS-Exchange) by using the following two tools

1. lighthouse
2. performance monitor in chrome devtools

As shown in the picture below, the lighthouse gives 1132 elements while the performance monitor gives 3631.

Why are they so different?

[image: result]

Comment: Elements are tagged nodes, but there are also whitespace nodes: `$x('//*/text()')`

Comment: Thanks. So the lighthouse only shows tagged nodes (i.e., `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`) while the performance monitor shows `$x('//*/text()')` in addition the tagged nodes? Is there any reference for that?